# three.js fade in/out post processing shaders

Tags: three.js, shader, fadein, fadeout, post-processing

I want to fade the scene into grayscale, but this also applies to other post-processing effects I'd like to fade in or out.

So for this example I'm using the THREE.ColorifyShader, but when activating it, the whole scene instantly receives the intended color

How can I "apply opacity/alpha" to post-processing?

Code example:

```
var effectColorify,
    copyPass;

    effectColorify = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.ColorifyShader);
    effectColorify.uniforms['color'].value.setRGB(0.8, 0.8, 0.8); // Grayscale

    copyPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.CopyShader);
    copyPass.renderToScreen = true;

    this.composerGrayscale = new THREE.EffectComposer(this.engine.renderer);
    this.composerGrayscale.addPass(this.renderPass);
    this.composerGrayscale.addPass(effectColorify);
    this.composerGrayscale.addPass(copyPass);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding an "opacity" uniform to the colorify shader. This allows to smoothly blend from the normal, colored, scene to a certain color by increasing opacity or the other way round.

```
effectColorify.uniforms['opacity'].value = 0.5; // 50% scene-color, 50% shader-color.
```

Here is the adjusted shader code you can copy into ColorifyShader.js, which is backwards compatible to the previous version, since default opacity is 1.0:

```
THREE.ColorifyShader = {

    uniforms: {

        "tDiffuse": { type: "t", value: null },
        "color":    { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
        "opacity":  { type: "f", value: 1.0 }

    },

    vertexShader: [

        "varying vec2 vUv;",

        "void main() {",

            "vUv = uv;",
            "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );",

        "}"

    ].join("\n"),

    fragmentShader: [

        "uniform float opacity;",
        "uniform vec3 color;",
        "uniform sampler2D tDiffuse;",

        "varying vec2 vUv;",

        "void main() {",

            "vec4 texel = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );",

            "vec3 luma = vec3( 0.299, 0.587, 0.114 );",
            "float v = dot( texel.xyz, luma );",

            "vec3 finalColor = vec3(",
                "(opacity * v * color.x) + ((1.0 - opacity) * texel.x),",
                "(opacity * v * color.y) + ((1.0 - opacity) * texel.y),",
                "(opacity * v * color.z) + ((1.0 - opacity) * texel.z)",
            ");",

            "gl_FragColor = vec4( finalColor, texel.w );",

        "}"

    ].join("\n")

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a timer to slowly increase the RGB values. or add it in the render loop, i'll use a timer, but the exact same loop can be applied in the render function.

```
var interval = 200; //interval for the animation in ms
var darkness = 1; //we'll start with a fade in, so we need the darknes at its biggest value
var fade = 'in';

var effectTimer = setInterval(function(){
    switch(fade){

        case 'in':
            if(darkness > 0){
                darkness -= 0.1;
            }
            else{
                fade = 'off';
            }
        break;

        case 'out':
            if(darkness < 1){
                darkness += 0.1;
            }
            else{
                fade = 'off';
            }
        break;
    }
    effectColorify.uniforms['color'].value.setRGB(darkness, darkness, darkness);
}, interval)
```

Comment: I found such an example, too, but that is not exactly what I'm looking for. Lets say I've got a nice and colorfur scene and now I want to fade this scene into grayscale, or red or white or whatsoever. Using the color uniform alone I can only go from grayscale (red, blue etc.) to black and back, but not from single-color to multi-color.
I think I have to add an opacity uniform value to the shader and apply the calculated value only with the factor given by opacity and then crossfade the opacity like in your example.

Comment: then you'd probably have to play with the [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) values instead of the RGB

Comment: HSL is just another way to writing RGB, the result is the same. I actually tried what I had in mind (adding opacity) and it works great. If you ever need that you can take the modified shader code from my answer.